# Creating a boolean array by testing if each element in numpy array is between 2 numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I have a numpy array of numbers and i want to create a boolean array of the same size and dimensions that says whether or not that element lies between 2 numbers. For example:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

I know if I write,

```
print a>3
```

I get an array that has the first three elements "False" and the rest "True"

```
np.array([[False,False,False],[True,True,True],[True,True,True]])
```

But i want to get a boolean array where the conditions are such that

```
a>3 and a<8
```

Is there a way to do this without checking every element one by one in a for loop? I have arrays that are 2048*2048 and that takes too long

Some has reported that is is the same question as another where the solution was to use the numpy.where function, but that returns the elements where a condition is true, my question is to return booleans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for a range like this:

```
print (3<a)&(a<8)
```

Comment: Oh okay thank you, i had tried different things and they didn't work 
    print a>3 and a<8
    print (a>3 and a<8)
    print (a>3) and (a<8)
    print (a>3 & a<8)
so i guess it was just the syntax...Thank you very much!

Comment: How to do this if you have starts and ends of ranges saved in a list of lists like this: `[[2,3],[8,10]]` for example, but you don't know before runtime, how many ranges are in there or which numbers are the starts and ends?